# How to find giant component of a network?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there a specific command in *Mathematica* 9 or 10 to extract the largest component of a given network which has one large and many small components?

The `ConnectedComponents` or `ConnectedGraphComponents` commands seem to do different than what I want in the question.

Answer (score 11):

You just need to wrap First around ConnectedComponents because the later sorts components by number of vertexes:

```
SeedRandom[1];
g = RandomGraph[{200, 130}];
HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, First[ConnectedComponents[g]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: For directed graphs `ConnectedComponents` are not sorted by `Length`:. e.g. `ConnectedComponents[
 Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 6 -> 7}]]` gives `{{5}, {4}, {1, 2, 3}, {7}, {6}}` .  So we do need to sort explicitly, and `Last@Sort@ConnectedComponents@g`  works for both directed and undirected graphs. (+1)

Comment: For directed, use `WeaklyConnectedComponents`.  `ConnectedComponents` would find strongly connected ones and would not sort by size in this case.